# MISGUIDED - htmlentities does not work

Tags: php, html

**UPDATE**

(I could just delete this question - but I might as well leave it as a reminder to everyone that sometimes the error is somewhere else than where we look...)

I am very sorry that I made you ponder this question: the reason for the "Actual result" was in a completely different location and has nothing to do with `htmlentities`.

Thanks to everyone who tried to help.

---

Why is this code not working in my PHP 5.4.32 site?

Code:

```
$returnValue = htmlentities(urldecode('//echo \'<textarea name="comments" id="comments">$theData</textarea>\';'), ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
echo '<textarea>' . $returnValue . '</textarea>';
```

**Expected result:**

A textarea with the exact string

```
//echo '<textarea name="comments" id="comments">$theData</textarea>';
```

**Actual result:**

A textarea with the exact string

```
//echo '<textarea name="comments" id="comments">$theData
```

(the "" in the original string actually closes the html textarea.)

In the same way, scripts can be injected (which is the reason why I originally used the htmlentities).

**The very strange thing:**

If I simply add the above example code to the beginning of my php file, it works as expected. So there must be some reason why it does not work further down the page. And I have no clue, see no possible reason in the code.

What's wrong?

btw: using `htmlspecialchars` doesn't change the effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this code. Works perfectly - the error was somewhere else in my php file...

Answer (score 3):

Dollar sign `$` isn't interpreted in single quotes.

Choose and use one of these:

```
echo '<textarea name="comments" id="comments">' . $theData . '</textarea>';
echo "<textarea name='comments' id='comments'>$theData</textarea>";
echo "<textarea name='comments' id='comments'>" . $theData . "</textarea>";
echo "<textarea name=\"comments\" id=\"comments\">$theData</textarea>";
```

Comment: this is a misunderstanding. `//echo '<textarea name="comments" id="comments">$theData</textarea>';` is simply the text string that should be displayed inside the outer textarea block.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `urldecode()` in this case. `urldecode()` will give you the original value of an url-encoded string (in PHP the return value of `urlencode()`). You're not working with url-encoded strings here.

The following should give you the expected result:

```
$returnValue = htmlentities('//echo \'<textarea name="comments" id="comments">$theData</textarea>\';', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
echo '<textarea>' . $returnValue . '</textarea>';
```

Comment: sorry, this does not change anything.